# datetime string (from python) to matlab

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have a datatime string (which comes from django/python) which looks like so:

```
datatime_str='2020-08-18 16:48:13.722422+00:00'
```

I then do, in Matlab 2018a:

```
fmt_dt='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+HH:mm';
datetime(datatime_str,'TimeZone','local','Format',fmt_dt);
```

and I get:

```
2020-08-18 00:00:13.722422+00:00
```

I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong, but the result is obviously wrong :(

Any help would be great

Comment: Which timezone do you belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the `+00:00` should be formatted as timezone, not hours, minute. However, you can set the display format as you would like, and this could be different from the input. The default Matlab `datetime` display format discards the fractional seconds (and also the timezone I think). For example:

```
fmt_dt_input='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxxxx';
fmt_dt_show='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS xxxxx';
datatime_str='2020-08-18 16:48:13.722422+00:00';

t =  datetime(datatime_str,'InputFormat',fmt_dt_input,'TimeZone','local','Format',fmt_dt_show)
```

Has as output: `2020-08-18 16:48:13.722422 +00:00`

EDIT: btw this info on `datetime` can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html?s_tid=srchtitle)

Comment: thanks a bunch for this - I also noticed that I needed to use `InputFormat` not `Fomat`

Answer (score 2):

your input string contains a UTC offset at the end, `+00:00` which you parse as hours and minutes - that is why they are set to 00:00 in the result. Use e.g.

```
datetime('2020-08-18 16:48:13.722422+00:00', 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ', 'TimeZone', 'UTC')
```

instead (change the TimeZone parameter to whatever you need).

Comment: This probably does not display the same as the input, since the default Matlab `datetime` display discards the fractional seconds in the display and also the timezone

Comment: @Nathan: right, I sometimes don't care so much how things are displayed, as long as it works correctly internally ;-)

Comment: Haha I understand.

Comment: @MrFuppes this works but the millisecond info seems missing :( Am I doing something wrong? Maybe it is just the display but how do I look at the entire value incl milliseconds?

Comment: @AJW: I think this is because I didn't provide a format as Nathan did in his answer